# What is sudo? I can't access to it

Tags: sudo

I am very very new to all of this.

I get it that sudo is some kind of authorisation. When it asks for the password, I can't type anything.

EDIT:
OMG GUYS THANKS. I just realized that I might have a solution for my wireless network now!! Well since I had no idea what Sudo was and when I tried to boot up 12.10 I couldn't since I thought I couldn't access to it! YES, I'm gonna try this out!

Comment: sudo has a long history - it comes from mainframes where they had to use the `pseudo` command for a program to invoke a system command as if a user had typed in the command - it was a pseudo user. The original bearded Unix boys picked up the sound of it (sue-doe) and realized it also could be SuperUser DO - so it became sudo, pronounced same as pseudo. It was a very useful joke. But that was many moons ago. Now the n00bs (that is, everybody born too late to remember watching the first moon landing live along with the rest of the world) use it.  It is fun to remember the history of these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually typing, it is just not shown there because someone should not watch it over your shoulder!

Answer (score 1):

When you type sudo into the terminal and it asks for your password, your password is not visible when you type it. So when you do happen to use the sudo command just type in your password even though you may not see it then hit enter.